# Resize UITextView when rotation in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, rotation, uitextview, cgrect

Hello i am facing a problem with `UITextView`.

In my app , i need to support both Portrait and Landscape.

So i added `UITextView` into my app and resize the frame of `UITextView` when keyboard appearing with following code because when keyboard appear , the `UITextView` is behind the keyboard and i can't see what i write in `UITextView`.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self moveTextViewForKeyboard:notification up:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self moveTextViewForKeyboard:notification up:NO];
}

- (void)moveTextViewForKeyboard:(NSNotification*)notification up:(BOOL)up {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    CGRect keyboardRect;

    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    animationDuration = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    keyboardRect = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];

    if (up == YES)
    {
        CGFloat keyboardTop = keyboardRect.origin.y;
        CGRect newTextViewFrame = self.txtView.frame;
        newTextViewFrame.size.height = keyboardTop - self.txtView.frame.origin.y - 10;
        self.txtView.frame = newTextViewFrame;
    }

    else
    {
        self.txtView.frame = originalCGRect;
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

That is fine when keyboard appear and not covering my `UITextView` anymore.
However when i rotate into Landscape , the `UITextView` frame is not correct anymore and also when i hide keyboard , it still remain like small size and not the fit with View.

[image]

[image]

How can i solve that problem?

Please help me.

Comment: If you are using latest version of iOS you can use Autolayout its best option.

Comment: Hope this will solve your problem http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: i can't use Autolayout bro because my app also support for iOS5. :(

Answer (score 1):

[image: can you trying to see Autoresizing mask try this one]

Try this i hope helpful to you....